# How to fill an object from a class with data from JSON data?

Tags: python, json

I want to fill my object with data received from JSON

Data keys from JSON are named the same as the parameters in my class.

is there any efficient way to create fill my object? hence my class will have over 50 variables.

**my testing Class:**

```
class Joint:
    spineX = 0.0
    spineY = 0.0
    spineZ = 0.0
```

**Json data:**

```
print(jsonData) #prints -> {"spineX":8.9,"spineY":7.7,"spineZ":9.9}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps add an `__init__` to your class:

```py
import json


class Joint:
    def __init__(self, spineX, spineY, spineZ):
        self.spineX = spineX
        self.spineY = spineY
        self.spineZ = spineZ


s = '{"spineX":8.9,"spineY":7.7,"spineZ":9.9}'
o = json.loads(s)
joint = Joint(**o)

print(vars(joint))
```

Comment: Thank you! very helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am going to append this answer cause you are talking about `class attributes` instead of `instance attributes`. You could use the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#setattr) `setattr`:

> This is the counterpart of `getattr()`. The arguments are an `object`, a
>   `string` and an arbitrary value. The `string` may name an existing
>   attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the
>   attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, `setattr(x,
>   'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

You can do this:

```
class Joint:
    spineX = 0.0
    spineY = 0.0
    spineZ = 0.0

s = '{"spineX":8.9,"spineY":7.7,"spineZ":9.9}'
o = json.loads(s)

for k in o.keys():
    setattr(Joint, k, o[k])

print(Joint.spineX)
print(Joint.spineY)
print(Joint.spineZ)
```

**Outputs:**

```
8.9
7.7
9.9
```

Now, every new instance of `Joint` will have those `class attribute` values. If you do this:

```
x = Joint()
print(x.spineX)
print(x.spineY)
print(x.spineZ)
```

You will also get:

```
8.9
7.7
9.9
```

In a more interesting note, with `setattr()` you can even add `class attributes` you haven't defined. For instance:

```
setattr(Joint, "spineA", 10.0)
print(Joint.spineA)
```

Will **output**:

```
10.0
```

Comment: THANK you! this answer contains the information i exactly wanted to know!

Comment: I have an additional question to this. I figured out same, but Iam not yet satisfied, because I would like to call the settattr within a staticmethod, whats actually not possible, because I want to avoid the seperate call. To have the json-attr available from beginning of class-declaration